Add labels to resources during install?
I would like to be able to add custom labels for my Kubernetes resources that gets created by installing a helm chart.
What I have tried is running:
helm install mychart . -l mylabel=123

However.. no such label shows up on the resources.
Am I missing the purpose of this flag? Or is the formating wrong?
Its documented here, and shows up while running helm install -h
https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/

You should be able to include metadata: { labels: } in your chart templates, and the default Helm boilerplate should include that.  What does your current template code look like?

First of all ensure that your templates use label key from the values.yaml:
labels:
    app: {{ .Chart.Name }}

Then set up your value in the values.yaml:
YourLabels:
  YourLabel1: "some-value"


Run

helm install <your-chart> . --set yourLabels.yourLabel1=yourlabel

